# Firebase Firestore. "Cost" onSnapshot

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I need to place an approximately 20 Vue component on the page. Each component, when mounted, creates an `onSnapshot` for itself and, accordingly, `unsubscribe()` when it is deleted.

```js
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('components').doc('comp1')

var unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
     ...
  })
}
```

What is the cost of each `onSnapshot` / `unsubscribe` :

1. in the sense of the execution time
2. in the sense of money (according to the price of Firebase)

How much will I pay, for example, if each of 1000 users update a page with 20 components 100 times in half an hour?

Perhaps it would be better to make `onSnapshot` on the whole `collection` of components?

Comment: If your concern is about reading/writing too many operations, you can switch to Firebase Realtime Database, as it only charges for bandwith and storage, contrary to Firestore whose cost depends on crud operations. [See documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore)

Comment: Thanks, but I just recently switched to firestore from Realtime Database! Realtime Database does not suit me for some reason.
I need to know if my decision is right or not. I would also like to understand the pricing of this particular solution, in order to determine whether it will be necessary to connect a paid plan or not.

Comment: Do all of your 20 components need to be updated realtime? You could have a mixed solution alternating to [fetching data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) and only enabling realtime updates on components that really need to

Comment: That is, my decision is "expensive" and should not be done this way?
Is it worth doing one `onSnapshot` for the whole collection of components?
That's better?

Comment: If all your data lives inside one collection, it would be a good approach

Comment: Yes, all in one collection. And then, I think, I can use Vuex.
`onSnapshot` is treated as a new request every time it is called (when the page is reloaded)? Or only when new data arrives?

Answer (score 11):

Found the information you need in [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing)

> **Listening to query results**
>
> Cloud Firestore allows you to listen to the results of a query and get realtime updates when the query results change.
>
> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is deleted, you are not charged for a read.)
>
> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query

So every time you update a record in your collection, all the suscribed users will perform a read. You should take your time in estimating the amount of active users you are going to have and the amount/frequency of your data, that will help in taking the cheapest and best solution that suits for your app.

I'm also adding the default [Firebase pricing calculator](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) which is at the bottom at the page and will definitely help you to take a decision.

Comment: "Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query"  Any idea what this part means?

Comment: I think it means that when the user comes back and the data updates that although it is not a "real-time snapshot" of data anymore you will still be charged as if it were